# Formatting Date and Datetime with SSIS Script Transformation

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a flat file containing dates like this: `07/07/2003 12:18:20 PM`.

The SSIS Transformation `Output Column` is set to database `timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]`.

I have the following method:

```
    public string DbDateTime(string input)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
    }
```

I need an output like this to the database:

```
2003-07-07 12:18:00.000
```

However, I keep getting an error:

*String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

The output is set like this:

```
Row.OuputDateTimeColumn = 
Convert.ToDateTime(DbDateTime(Row.InputDateTimeColumn));
```

I prefer not to use a `Derived Column` for the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** You are providing invalid custom format for both Month and Date feilds.

you have two fixed digits in your Date String but you are only providing one digit format  as below:

```
"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

so you need to Replace this as below:

if your DateString hour format is `00-12`

```
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
```

if your DateString hour format is `0-12`

```
 "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

**Problem 2:** You want to return the Date String in custom format of `2003-07-07 12:18:00.000` i assume it is in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss.ffff`.

**Note:** as both `Month` and `Date` are same(07) in your example, you need to adjust them accordingly if my assumption is wrong.

so you need to provide the above custom format to the `ToString()` function in the return statement.

**Complete Code:**

```
public string DbDateTime(string input)
{
 return DateTime.ParseExact(input, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss.fff");
}
```

**Problem 3:** while adding the Custom DateFormat to the database you need to first convert it into the DateTime as below:

```
Row.OuputDateTimeColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(
   DbDateTime(Row.InputDateTimeColumn),"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss.fff"  
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hello my friends: Still getting the same error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy: which format you are providing? and what is the format of your date string? aare there two fixed digits for hours? can you post your latest code??

Comment: I am following the exact code posted here: I created an Output Column with Datatype: `database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]`. I noticed when I tested the code like this in a console app. I get the same date format from the start: `Console.Write(DateTime.ParseExact(DbDateTime("07/07/2003 12:18:20 PM"), "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`

Comment: @UnaverageGuy: okay let me check it once

Comment: @UnaverageGuy: from the console app its working for me try this-> `Console.Write(DateTime.ParseExact(DbDateTime("07/07/2003 12:18:20 PM"));`

Comment: Okay: This works! I changed the Method to type `DateTime`. 
`        public DateTime DbDateTime(string input)
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }`
Then converted the output from the method to the output column. `Row.OuputDateTimeColumn = Convert.ToDateTime(Row.InputDateTimeColumn);`

Answer (score 1):

Your format is wrong. It doesn't match with your input string. Use `MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` format instead. For example;

```
public string DbDateTime(string input)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(input,
                               "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).
                               ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss.fff");
}
```

From [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

[`M`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier) is for `1` to `12` but [`MM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) is for `01` to `12`.

[`d`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dSpecifier) is for `1` to `31` but [`dd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier) is for `01` to `31`.

Also be carefull about your hour forma. `h` is for `1` to `12`, `hh` is for `01` to `12`. If you want to use *24-hour format*, you need to use `H` or `HH` formats.

For more informations, take a look;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)